# Systemd-timesyncd FallbackNTP never used

Tags: systemd, systemd-timesyncd

I use systemd-timesyncd to run NTP time synchronization. I want to specify two servers, one company internal (not available from outside), and one from the public internet:

```
[Time]
NTP=ntp.mycompany.net
FallbackNTP=pool.ntp.org
```

However, if the device is outside the company network and the internal server is not available, timesyncd never switches over to the FallbackNTP.

```
user@device:~# timedatectl timesync-status
   Server: n/a (ntp.mycompany.net)
   Poll interval: 0 (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
   Packet count: 0
```

What am I overlooking here? Thanks!

Comment: Note that if I add both servers into one line it works: `NTP=ntp.mycompany.net pool.ntp.org`

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found some reference on this in the systemd bug tracker:

> The FallbackNTP= setting (like the FallbackDNS= setting in
> resolved.conf) configures the servers to use when no other servers can
> be determined. If there are other servers (like the ones you defined
> via NTP=) declared then they are ignored.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/15644